# Use selenium for python to automatically click on email from example@gmail.com

Tags: python, xpath, automation, gmail

I want to automatically click on an email from example@gmail.com and I know there will be only one email from that person so it won’t be a problem with two identical emails.

I have tried to locate the XPath for the email and that works fine. But when i try to click on it with `webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("XPath of the email").click()` the XPath is not clickable.

[image]

As far as I tried I was only able to specify which row `<tr></tr>` i wanted to click on `webdriver.find element_by_xpath("XPath of row").click()` and it clicks on it.

[image]

Is it somehow possible to click on a row that contains a specific email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below xpath to get the row that contains `example@gmail.com` span.

**Option 1:**

```
//span[@email='example@gmail.com']/ancestor::tr[@role='row']
```

**Option 2:**

```
//tr[@role='row'][.//span[@email='example@gmail.com']]
```

**Screenshot :**
[image]

Comment: Haven’t tried option 2 but option 1 worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your syntax is not correct,
This should be

> webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("XPath of the email").click()

like this

> webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the email']")).click();

If the id is same, it should also suffice to use just the `find_element_by_id()` method instead of the xpath.

```
element = firefox.find_element_by_id("the_id")#if the id is the same
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def link_gm(self):
    self.browser.get('https://mail.google.com/')
def next_process(self):
    self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys("Your mail id")
    self.actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@type="password"]').send_keys('Your password')
    self.actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[16]/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]').click()

    time.sleep(5)
    first_mail = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'(//*[@tabindex="-1"])[16]')
    self.actions.move_to_element(first_mail).perform()
    self.actions.click().perform()
    time.sleep(10)
```

By this code you can open your first mail in selenium

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).